# Deleting a row from DataSet doesn't affect the database

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I'm new at `ADO.NET` and I'm trying to understand the disconnected model, I wrote a code to do inset update and delete using `SqlDataAdapter` and `SqlCommandBuilder` and it worked with insert and update but not with delete, why is this?, and how to fix it?.

Here is my code inside the event handler, I have one table "client" that have 3 columns id, name, city, and my DataSet Called ds.

```
SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from client", cnx);       
foreach (DataRow client in ds.Tables["client"].Rows)
{
    if (client.Field<int>(0) == 100)
    {
        ds.Tables["client"].Rows.Remove(client);
        break;
    }
}
new SqlCommandBuilder(ad);
ad.Update(ds, "client");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you remove the row, there is no way for the Update method to discover which row has been removed. You need to use the Delete method

```
foreach (DataRow client in ds.Tables["client"].Rows)
{
  if (client.Field<int>(0) == 100)
  {
      client.Delete();
      break;
  }
}
```

When you call the Delete method, the [RowState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.rowstate?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataRow_RowState) property of the deleted row changes to *DataRowState.Deleted* but it is still present in the DataSet. So when you call the Update, the method now is able to search for all the rows that have a *RowState* different from *DataRowState.Unchanged* and executes the appropriate action against the database table

Comment: thanks for the solution and the explanation it worked